# Get catalog rule by customer group id Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalog, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I would like to get the catalog rule using a customer group id.

I cant seem to find a method for it.

How would I go on about doing this in Magento 2?

Comment: have you tried with Catalog Price Rule?

Comment: @MoinMalek I can't seem to find a corresponding method over here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogRule/Model/Rule.php

Comment: Please check setCustomerGroupIds method into this file Magento/SalesRule/Model/Data/Rule.php File

Comment: @MoinMalek I have checked it but I can't seem to figure it out